# Read multiple DataFrames from PyODBC

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

I have a list of IDs that I am looping through,

```
ids = [201,202,203,204,205,206,207]
```

Now, I am looping through each id and getting values for those ids.

```
for i in ids:
cu.execute('select var1, var2, var3 from tbl where id = 'i'')
```

In my next for loop, I created an empty list and getting all the values for each id.

```
values = []
for j in cu:
    values.append(j)
    df = func(values)
```

Here, `func` creates a pandas dataframe for those appended `values` list. After runing this, it saves everything in a one big dataframe.

My question is, how can i save each `id`'s values that I am getting into every single list or pandas data frame instead of one big data frame?

Comment: Create a list of data frames?

Comment: @COLDSPEED That is promising. Is it going to be in dictionary format?

Comment: Only if it makes sense to use a dictionary and ordering doesnt matter. Else, just append to a list of dfs.

Comment: @COLDSPEED It would be nice if it is ordered, and If you could provide an example, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to separate out your data by ID, you can append each iteration's data to a list called `df_list`.

```
df_list = []
for i in ids:
    cursor.execute(
        'select var1, var2, var3 from tbl where id = ?', (i,))
    df_list.append(func([j for j in cursor]))
```

I've replaced the inner loop with a list comprehension. Once `values` is filled, you call `func` once and append the returned data frame to the `df_list`.

Comment: Perfect, this works! Now I can iterate through each item in `df_list` :) thank you!